Visual Studio 2022 Color for autocomplete or errors
I'd like to change the background colour of the red-ish and green-ish boxes on the screenshot below. I get these, when there's an error in my code and I click on the text underlined in red.
I can't find any colour in my settings that come close to this, so what could it be? I also have no idea about a search term to use.


Sometimes the default setting of the background box color of the selected text will change with the background color of the editor, the background color in your screenshot is dark blue, I didn't find the relevant setting to set this color, please tell me the type of project you use.

It's a C# project. An Autodesk-Revit plugin to be specific. In "Selected Text" my background colour is blue: RGB 0,120,215

Regarding changing the background color (red and light yellow) of the nodes in the code on the left side of the picture you provided, you can modify it in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display items > Highlighted Reference and Highlighted Definition. Regarding the function of the arrow shown on the right side of the picture, can you tell me where you turned it on?

Both of these are set to blue. I have no idea where I enabled that option and it's hard to reproduce it. It has to do with the smart autocomplete, that suggests the next part of code you want to write. I replaced the name of a member and then changed the member name in all calls to that member.

When I tested changing the color of Highlighted Reference and Highlighted Definition, the related references and definitions all changed to the color I specified. If the color of your Highlighted Reference and Highlighted Definition is set to blue, and the background color of the nodes is still red and light yellow, then it has something to do with your plugin.
